# Python, combobox does not modify elements with IF

Tags: tkinter

I'm starting out with Tkinter in Python. I'm having a hard time doing a simple thing. There are two comboboxes. For example, selecting the text "" Test1 "in the first combobox Category, I would like Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3" to open in the second combobox Subcategory.

Maybe I wrote the code wrong from the start. I would like to ask you 2 things:

1. Can you help me with my IF problem?
2. I think I haven't written the right code from the first line. Can you give me a system of all the code please? Fortunately it is not long Thank you

   ```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    import sqlite3

    window=Tk()
    window.title("aaaa")
    window.geometry("700x700")

    categoria=["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
    categoria=ttk.Combobox(window,value=categoria,width=16)
    categoria.place(x=5, y=100)
    categoria.set("Scegliere categoria")
    categoria.pack

    sottocategoria=["aaaa"]
    sottocategoria=ttk.Combobox(window,value=sottocategoria,width=16)
    sottocategoria.place(x=5, y=130)
    sottocategoria.pack

    if categoria == ("Test1"):
    sottocategoria = ["Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3"]


    window.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: You need to trace the variable to detect any changes in the values

Comment: You should read more about event driven programming.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65990242/509977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trace the variable. You are basically doing procedural programming and python reads from top to button. But when you assign the value, and it goes to the `if` statement, the value evaluates to False. Then the `mainloop` is just the loop to show the window. Also, you can use a `StringVar()` to get the values and detect any changes.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window=Tk()
cat=StringVar()
sub_cat=StringVar()
def change_val(*args):
    if cat.get() == "Test1":
        sottocategorias = ["Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
    else:
        sottocategorias = ["aaaa"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
window.title("aaaa")
window.geometry("700x700")
categorias=["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
categoria=ttk.Combobox(window,value=categorias,textvariable=cat,width=16)
categoria.place(x=5, y=100)
cat.set("Scegliere categoria")
sottocategorias=["aaaa"]
sottocategoria=ttk.Combobox(window,textvariable=sub_cat,value=sottocategorias,width=16)
sottocategoria.place(x=5, y=130)


cat.trace("w",change_val)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is a virtual event, `<<ComboboxSelected>>` that you can use instead of `trace`.

Comment: ok @CoolCloud, I was not aware of that. Thank you

Comment: Why is there `categoria.pack` after using `place` on it? I tried copy pasting the code, but it does not do what the OP wants.